# Stop Event bubbling for a disabled element

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

I have a button that has a style

```
pointer-events: none;
```

And this button has a parent element that performs a collapsible event. I don't know how to prevent this button from triggering its parent elements collapsible event. This is caused because of the button style which is pointer-events: none

Thanks

Comment: If you show us the html then we might be able to help :)

Comment: pointer-events is not the way to disable an element, it just cancels all pointer events, and is helpful it you're doing something that requires pointer events on an underlying element.

Comment: you need e.stopPropagation()

Comment: @adeneo - yes i need the pointer-events to prevent the pointer events on that element. But when a user clicks on this element its triggering its parent element's action which I don't want to.

Comment: If you're sure you know what pointer-events are, and how to use them, that's fine, but it doesn't really sound like pointer-events is what you need. Anyway, in the event handler for the parent element just do a `e.target === this` check, or stop the propagation, but I'm not sure that would work on an element that has no pointer events, and when clicking such an element you're really clicking right throu it, so you most likely **are** clicking the parent element, at least if that element is "behind" the element with no pointer-events, as that's the whole point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the following html:

```
<div class="collapsible">
    <button>Hi</button>
</div>
```

You could do something like this:

```
$('.collapsible').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).children('button').css('pointer-events') == 'none') return;

    //do collapse
});
```

or maybe this:

```
$('.collapsible').click(function(e) {        
    //do collapse
});

$('.collapsible button').click(function(e) {
   if ($(this).css('pointer-events') == 'none')
       e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: An element with `pointer-events:none` won't trigger the event handler

Answer (score 1):

As @adeneo said, if you use `pointer-events: none` on the child, then parent's event listener can't know if the target is itself or its child.
It's like when you click some text inside a paragraph, the event listener can't know if you clicked the text or paragraph's padding.

Then, you can use

```
document.getElementById('outer').onclick = function(e) {
    /* your code */
};
document.getElementById('outer').addEventListener('click',  function(e) {
    if(e.target !== this) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}, true);
```

WITHOUT `pointer-events: none`.

This way, you use capture phase, so you can prevent the execution of children's event handlers  (like `pointer-events: none`), but now you can distinguish if the user clicked your element or its children.

**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5N7L/3/)**

**Problem**: You can't use capture phase on old versions of IE.

**Advantage**: Since it doesn't work on old IE, you don't have to worry about things like

- `e = e || window.event`
- `e.target || e.srcElement`
- `if (e.stopPropagation) { e.stopPropagation(); } else { e.calcelBubble=true; }`